# Header is included in module but not listed in module map

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-frameworks

I have 2 iOS frameworks in two separate projects where FrameworkA is included by FrameworkB.

The code runs fine except I see these warnings when building FrameworkB

```
Header'/Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerviedData/<lengthy unique folder name>/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FrameworkA.framework/Modules/module.modulemap' is included in module 'FrameworkA' but not listed in module map <module-includes>

Header'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimualtor8.1sdk/System/Library/Framework/UIKit.framework/module.modulemap' is included in module 'FrameworkA' but not listed in module map <module-includes>

Header'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolschains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.0/include/module.modulemap' is included in module 'FrameworkA' but not listed in module map <module-includes>
```

there are a couple more like this in the warnings list

Comment: have you found the solution to this problem?

Comment: Be sure to add your headers to the umbrella header

Comment: what does your umbrella header look like?